# Как исправить значительную потерю скорости через OpenVPN (TCP)?

Tags: windows, centos, vpn, openvpn

Впервые настраиваю OpenVPN на CentOS7:
Сервер — маленький VPS, канал 200/200mbit;
Клиент — Windows 7, канал **40**/**40**mbit.

Спустя двое суток глубокого гугления, опробовал десятки вариантов конфигурации, сейчас остановился на самой производительной, которая даёт всего **12**/**8**mbit по замерам на SpeedTest.
Во время максимальной нагрузки на канал, нагрузка CPU ~15%.

**Конфигурация сервера**

```html
port 443
proto tcp
dev tun
user nobody
group nobody
persist-key
persist-tun
keepalive 10 120
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp" 
crl-verify crl.pem
ca ca.crt
cert server_cR0qH59D9aI9rtXh.crt
key server_cR0qH59D9aI9rtXh.key
tls-auth tls-auth.key 0
dh dh.pem
auth SHA256
cipher AES-128-CBC
tls-server
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256
status openvpn.log
verb 3

sndbuf 524288
rcvbuf 524288
push "sndbuf 524288"
push "rcvbuf 524288"
tun-mtu 6000
mssfix 0
```

**Конфигурация клиента**

```html
client
proto tcp-client
remote 185.20.*.* 443
dev tun
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
verify-x509-name server_cR0qH59D9aI9rtXh name
auth SHA256
auth-nocache
cipher AES-128-CBC
tls-client
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256
setenv opt block-outside-dns

verb 4
sndbuf 524288
rcvbuf 524288
tun-mtu 6000
mssfix 0
```

**cat /etc/sysctl.conf**

```html
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
net.core.rmem_max = 6291456
net.core.wmem_max = 4194304
net.core.wmem_default = 212992
net.core.rmem_default = 212992
```

Comment: На скока я знаю - openvpn работает в юзерспейсе и нифига не ядерный. Так что тормоза - "это норма".

Comment: Авторы топиков о проблемах в скорости иногда писали, что начало работать где-то на 70-80% от канала, тоже так хочу

Comment: Ну а примеры настроек они не приводили?

Comment: Приводили, но когда ставлю их себе — становится либо хуже, либо ничего не меняется